# Pager(Tablesort plugin) doesn't work in Spring View

Tags: jquery, spring, tablesorter, pager

i'm sorry if this a duplicate question but i have spent hours looking for a solution without succeed. And sorry too for the bad English, is not my native language. :(

This is my problem:

I have a web application handled by **Spring 3.0.5**. One of my **JSP** files retrieve data from a database and put it into a table, this is workig fine.
I'm trying to use the jquery plugin **tablesort** to sort the fields in the table, this worked fine for me too so i try to use the pager addon and that's when my fairy story falls.

I have defined a form with an **"id=anyname"** at the end of my table, as the docs in the web of tablesorter said, and call it in a script but it doesn't work.

Here i left my JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css"/>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" />"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#consulta")
        .tablesorter({
            headers: { 0: { sorter: false }, 1: { sorter: false }, 6: { sorter: false }},
            sortList: [[2, 0], [0, 0]],
            widthFixed: true,
            widgets: ['zebra']})
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
/*
*
*
*
*/
<table id="consulta" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>C&oacute;digo</th>
            <th>Especialidad</th>
            <th>Asunto</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Ciclo</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${consultaSol}" var="solic">
            <c:url var="verUrl" value="/manage/mgmtSol/detalle?id=${solic.id}" />
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${solic.codigo}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${solic.especialidad}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${solic.asunto}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${solic.fecha}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${solic.ciclo}" /></td>
        <c:if test="${solic.estado == 0 }">
            <td>No atendido</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${solic.estado == 1 }">
            <td>Atendido</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${solic.estado == 2 }">
            <td>Resuelto</td>
        </c:if>
            <td><a href="${verUrl}">Ver Detalle</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="<c:url value="/resources/imagenes/first.png" />" class="first"/>
        <img src="<c:url value="/resources/imagenes/prev.png" />" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" readonly="readonly"/>
        <img src="<c:url value="/resources/imagenes/next.png" />" class="next"/>
        <img src="<c:url value="/resources/imagenes/last.png" />" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, as a i said before the tablesort is working fine but the pager option don't. By the way i was using jquery 1.9.1 and the changed it to 1.8.2 version but it doesn't work.

Also, when i run the application, the Chrome developer tool shows one error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined
```

but i don't understand it, it's from the jquery-1.8.2.js file.

Help me please!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, your English is actually alright. A few grammatical things, but it's readable, and that's the important thing!

Comment: If you are using the [original tablesorter v2.0.5](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), it will cause errors in jQuery 1.9+ due to it using the `$.browser` function... can you modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/474/) to show us how you get that error? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, maybe there was something sticked in cache but when I changed the jquery version to 1.8.3, as your jsfiddle demo, my project start to worked just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mootie for the response.
The problem was in the jquery version, it seems that tablesorter v2.0.5 cause errors in jQuery 1.9+.
So i changed my jquery version to 1.8.3 and it worked just fine.

Thanks again to Mottie for give me that info.
Greetings.